# how do I match and find a vector in a Numpy array?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, indexing

I have a Numpy array with size [2000,6].now I have an array with size [1,6] and I want to know which row of the main Numpy array is the same as this [1,6] array. if it exists in the main array, return the index of the row. for example row 1. but I do not want to use `for` loops because it is really time-consuming.  I do not know how I can find a vector in an array and extract its related index. please help me with this issue. Thanks

Comment: There are no rows in one-dimensional list.

Comment: Do you have a numpy array or a python list?

Comment: Can you show the code that creates this data/object?

Comment: @OlvinRoght they specified dimensions `[2000,6]` though the cell looks 1-dimensional.

Comment: @JesseH., I commented on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/73241232/1) redaction of question, before edits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using NumPy for this, your goal can be obtained by using the `numpy.where` method.

## NumPy Solution

You can ignore this cell as I am just creating a simulated version of your problem:

```
# Simulate @david data
import numpy as np

target_row = np.array((7, 8, 9, 1, 2, 1))
simulated_array = np.zeros((2000, 6))

# I put the target row in index 3
simulated_array[3] = target_row
```

```py
# Solution
import numpy as np

target_row = np.array((7, 8, 9, 1, 2, 1))
condition = simulated_array == target_row
where_result = np.where(condition)

# This is required since a row of indices is returned above
target_index = where_result[0]
```

## Python List solution

```py
# Simulate @david array

simulated_list = array.tolist()
target_list = [7, 8, 9, 1, 2, 1]
```

```py
# Solution
target_list = [7, 8, 9, 1, 2, 1]
target_index = simulated_list.index(target_list)
```

## Resources

`numpy.where` — https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html

Comment: @JesseH.Thank you. it was the thing I need.

Answer (score 0):

this is what I have, though I imagine theres some method in np.arrays that could do this for you

```
import numpy as np
arr = np.array([[1, 2 ,3, 4, 5, 6],[7, 8 ,9, 1, 2, 1],[ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ,6]])
    for index in arr:
        if index == [7, 8 ,9, 1, 2, 1]:
            print(index)
```

Comment: as I said it is a NumPy array with 2000 rows and 6 columns. now I need to match a vector with 6 columns and one row in the main array and if it exists, return the index of the row for example row 2.

Comment: but I do not want to use for loops because it is very time-consuming. is it a way to find without for loops

Comment: @david to be fair, you did not mention NumPy